# lambda with reduce error in Python3

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I am trying to use reduce as follows:

`>>> reduce(lambda z,(x,y): (z+1) if x == y else z, [(3, 4), (5, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5)], 0)`

In Python 2.7 I get the expected:

```
2
```

While the exact same line returns the following error in Python 3.5:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
reduce(lambda z,(x,y): (z+1) if x == y else z, [(3, 4), (5, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5)], 0)
                ^
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Any suggestions as to what the syntax should be for Python 3? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is actually a consequence of the fact that tuple argument unpacking has been removed in python 3. Check [PEP3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: Although you can fix the error here, a more elegant way is probably `sum(x == y for x, y in data)` with `data` the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***tuple pattern matching*** was removed from python 3, so try:

```
reduce(lambda z, x: (z+1) if x[0] == x[1] else z, [(3, 4), (5, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5)], 0)
```

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ commented, check [PEP3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)